# MongoDb query array with date, filter per date range

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
dataRanges: 
[
  {
    "name":"dataRange_0",
    "range" : [
      {
        "dateStart": "2000-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "dateEnd": "2005-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      {
        "dateStart": "2010-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "dateEnd": "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      }
    ],
  "name":"dataRange_1",
    "range" : [
      {
        "dateStart": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "dateEnd": "2025-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

To query the data, I create a `MatchOperation` with `MongoUtils.getAndCriteria(List<Criteria>)` and then I use `MongoOperations.aggregate`.
The field `range` represents the range in which there is data.
I want to keep the dataRanges that has data between (inclusive) two specified dates (`Instant: dateStartFilter, Instant: dateEndFilter`) using `Criteria` that I put in my `List<Criteria>`
I've been able to do a `Criteria` match that works with only a `dateStartFilter`or a `dateEndFilter`:

```
//dateStart filter
if (dateStartFilterExists)
  where("range.dateEnd").gte(dateStartFilter);

//dateEnd filter
if (dateEndFilterExists)
  where("range.dateStart").lte(dateEndFilter);
```

I want to get every dataRange after x date, and every dataRange before x date using those filters.

I have a problem when I want to use a dateStartFilter AND a dateEndFilter.
Using the example dataRanges, if I set my values to :

```
Instant dateStartFilter = "2006-01-01T00:00:00Z";
Instant dateEndFilter = "2009-01-01T00:00:00Z";
```

It will still return `dataRange_0` even if it is between the values.
How can I make it work?
My theory is that it check every range at the same time resulting in this logic :

```
dateStartFilter (2006-01-01T00:00:00Z) < dateEnd (2015-01-01T00:00:00Z) = true
dateEndFilter (2009-01-01T00:00:00Z) > dateStart (2000-01-01T00:00:00Z) = true
```

Is there a way to force the Criteria match for one element of the array at a time?
Also I've tried this too without success:
`where(dateEnd).gte(dateStartFilter).andOperator(where(dateStart).lte(dateEndFilter);`

I hope I explained my problem correctly. I'm still looking if I can use another type of `AggregationOperation` to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: "_Is there a way to force the Criteria match for one element of the array at a time?_" - yes, this is exactly what `$elemMatch` is for

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about $elemMatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after some time, I figured I should answer this thread if anyone find it.

```
Criteria.where("range").elemMatch(
  new Criteria().andOperator(
    Criteria.where("dateEnd").gte(dateStartFilter),
    Criteria.where("dateStart").lte(dateEndFilter)
  )
);
```

Important thing when you call `elemMatch()`, you are in that object.
Don't do `"range.dateEnd" / "range.dateStart"` in the match :P